# Fill empty cells in google sheets after using IMPORTHTML to populate with webpage table

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am populating my google sheet with a web table using the IMPORTHTML() command. The sheet fills up successfully, however, in the source table, some cells are empty and so is in the google sheet which is expected. The google sheet is dynamic, i.e, the data refreshes periodically as the source web table gets updated. I want to fill the empty cells with a default value (e.g, 0). Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

multiply it by 1 if your table is all numeric:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTHTML("url", "table", 1)*1)
```

otherwise:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTHTML("url", "table", 1)="", 0, IMPORTHTML("url", "table", 1))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this just yesterday and it worked:

`=ArrayFormula((IF(ISBLANK(IMPORTHTML("url", "table", 1)), "0", IMPORTHTML("url", "table", 1))))`